# Workflow only triggered on manual execution even though it's set to trigger on creation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow

My workflow on sharepoint doesn't execute when a new item is created in the associated list.

The workflow uses a list item which contains a number and copies that into a reference number field on the new/current item.

I've checked that:

1. workflow is set to run on item creation
2. all logs are written on manual release
3. the workflow is executing correctly when ran manually

   Is there any more troubleshooting I can do to check what's wrong?

Comment: Check you are not using System Account for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Check you are not using System Account for testing.

1. Workflow will never start automatically with system account.
2. Check the options Start workflow automatically when an item is created or changed from Workflow Start Options.